# TypeChecker cannot resolve types or symbols

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-compiler-api

Trying to creating a simple transformer, creating a SourceFile object manually using `createSourceFile` function works fine, but the `TypeChecker` cannot find types or symbols at all.

When creating a program using the code below, only declaration files in `node_modules` are found, my guess that the `TypeChecker` cannot find types/symbols because it doesn't know about my source files, I'm using typescript version `3.5.2`

```
const fileNames = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log(fileNames);
const program = createProgram(fileNames, {
    target: ScriptTarget.ES5,
    module: ModuleKind.CommonJS
});
const checker = program.getTypeChecker();
for (const sourceFile of program.getSourceFiles()) {
    console.log(sourceFile.fileName);

}

// [ 'path/to/my/file.ts' ]

// ..../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.d.ts
// ..../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts
// ..../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.d.ts
// ..../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2016.d.ts
// ..../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.d.ts
// ..../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2018.d.ts
// ..../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts
// .... more declaration files only, none of my source files are found
```

Am I creating the program wrong, do I have to scan for files myself? any help is appreciated (Links to updated docs, or related questions/issues etc)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code and double checking it, it works fine for me. It's probably just not able to find the files based on the file paths provided. Perhaps try resolving the array of file names to absolute paths? (ex. `import * as path from "path"; const fileNames = process.argv.slice(2).map(f => path.resolve(f)); console.log(fileNames);`). They're probably not relative to the directory the script is being run from.

Comment: By the way, I think you are meaning to say that the program cannot resolve the provided file paths? This should work regardless of creating a type checker.

Comment: I tried passing a relative and full path (and a `.`) all with the same result, creating the AST will work for a single file using `createSourceFile`, you have to create the program and type checker separately.

Comment: Is the code you're working with exactly the same as the code above? The code above works for me when the provided paths are correct. -- Perhaps check the result of `console.log(ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program));`. Do you see anything in there?

Comment: I just tried running my example again, but this time running `ts-node src/cli.ts` instead of `tsc && node dist/cli.js`, now my source file is found and the type-checker can resolve types/symbols from nodes.